# Error: Property "sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output" was not specified Sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

I'm configuring my sonarqube to run on my project, following the instructions given to run from the cloud I have my file like this:

```
sonar.projectKey=yisera_aaswtest
sonar.projectName=aaswtest
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.language=js
sonar.profile=node
sonar.exclusions=node_modules, migrations, models_old, seeders, .gitignore
```

I downloaded sonarqube CLI, copied the bin file to `%path%` on windows but for some reason, after running the test, I get the following error:

`Property "sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output" was not specified`

As you can see, my project is in javascript(nodejs specifically) and not C++, and even then, for some reason it's scanning my node_modules folder while I explicitly state in my properties file to exclude scanning there.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Here is the command I run:

```
sonar-scanner.bat -Dsonar.projectKey=yisera_aaswtest -Dsonar.organization=yisera-bitbucket -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io -Dsonar.login=cc10c0f538a6b50c876c2c53ed479eadd3e60988
```